# using ffmpeg hwaccel from C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

How do I decode a file with hardware acceleration with ffmpeg?

I have written a working video player that uses ffmpeg.
I have checked for support using `"av_hwaccel_next"` and found `mpeg2_dxva`.

However, when I load an mpeg2 file (as usual) I do not get any hardware acceleration. `AVCodecContext->hwaccel` and `AVCodecContext->hwaccelcontext` are both null.

Do I have to pass some flag somewhere in order to enable hw-acceleration?

I haven't been able to find any information regarding this, anyone know of a good source?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Start from reading ffmpeg documentation: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro and better answer [How to use hardware acceleration with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289157/how-to-use-hardware-acceleration-with-ffmpeg) (and for linux check page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration)

> When using FFmpeg the tool, HW-assisted decoding is enabled using through the `-hwaccel` option, which enables a specific decoder. Each decoder may have specific limitations (for example an H.264 decoder may only support baseline profile). HW-assisted encoding is enabled through the use of a specific encoder (for example h264_nvenc). Filtering HW-assisted processing is only supported in a few filters ..
>   There are several hardware acceleration standards API, **some of which are supported** to some extent by FFmpeg.

hwaccel activation was controlled by code like (bit reformatted after 2013 https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/08303d774132775d49d4ba767092de5d426f089d)

```
avctx->hwaccel = ff_find_hwaccel(avctx->codec->id, avctx->pix_fmt);
```

For example, in libavcodec/mpeg12dec.c https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/6c7254722ad43712db5686feee8bf75c74d8635b/libavcodec/mpeg12dec.c

```
avctx->pix_fmt = mpeg_get_pixelformat(avctx);
avctx->hwaccel = ff_find_hwaccel(avctx->codec->id, avctx->pix_fmt);
```

The `ff_find_hwaccel` checks codec and pixelformat pair of image and of all available hwaccelerators.

```
AVHWAccel *ff_find_hwaccel(enum CodecID codec_id, enum PixelFormat pix_fmt)
{
    AVHWAccel *hwaccel=NULL;

    while((hwaccel= av_hwaccel_next(hwaccel))){
        if (   hwaccel->id      == codec_id
            && hwaccel->pix_fmt == pix_fmt)
            return hwaccel;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

For example, dxva2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX_Video_Acceleration) has:

```
AVHWAccel mpeg2_dxva2_hwaccel = {
    .name           = "mpeg2_dxva2",
    .type           = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,
    .id             = CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO,
    .pix_fmt        = PIX_FMT_DXVA2_VLD,
    .capabilities   = 0,
    .start_frame    = start_frame,
    .decode_slice   = decode_slice,
    .end_frame      = end_frame,
    .priv_data_size = sizeof(struct dxva2_picture_context),
};
```

And `libavutil/pixfmt.h` lists all supported hw decoders / accelerators by their pixel formats https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/pixfmt_8h.html

```
AV_PIX_FMT_XVMC_MPEG2_MC    - XVideo Motion Acceleration via common packet passing.
AV_PIX_FMT_XVMC_MPEG2_IDCT  - undocumented
AV_PIX_FMT_XVMC         - undocumented
AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_H264   - H.264 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers.
AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_MPEG1  - MPEG-1 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers.
AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_MPEG2  - MPEG-2 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers.
AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_WMV3   - WMV3 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers.
AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_VC1    - VC-1 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers. 
AV_PIX_FMT_VAAPI_MOCO   - HW acceleration through VA API at motion compensation entry-point, Picture.data[3] contains a vaapi_render_state struct which contains macroblocks as well as various fields extracted from headers.
AV_PIX_FMT_VAAPI_IDCT   - HW acceleration through VA API at IDCT entry-point, Picture.data[3] contains a vaapi_render_state struct which contains fields extracted from headers.
AV_PIX_FMT_VAAPI_VLD    - HW decoding through VA API, Picture.data[3] contains a VASurfaceID. 
AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_MPEG4  - MPEG-4 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers.
AV_PIX_FMT_DXVA2_VLD    - HW decoding through DXVA2, Picture.data[3] contains a LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 pointer. 
AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU        - HW acceleration through VDPAU, Picture.data[3] contains a VdpVideoSurface. 
AV_PIX_FMT_VDA          - HW acceleration through VDA, data[3] contains a CVPixelBufferRef. 
AV_PIX_FMT_QSV          - HW acceleration through QSV, data[3] contains a pointer to the mfxFrameSurface1 structure.
AV_PIX_FMT_MMAL         - HW acceleration though MMAL, data[3] contains a pointer to the MMAL_BUFFER_HEADER_T structure.
AV_PIX_FMT_D3D11VA_VLD  - HW decoding through Direct3D11, Picture.data[3] contains a ID3D11VideoDecoderOutputView pointer.
AV_PIX_FMT_CUDA         - HW acceleration through CUDA. data[i] contain CUdeviceptr pointers exactly as for system memory frames.
```

Actual selection of pixel formats is in function called before `ff_find_hwaccel`, the `static enum PixelFormat mpeg_get_pixelformat(AVCodecContext *avctx)` of `libavcodec/mpeg12dec.c` for mpeg1/2. In earlier versions of ffmpeg/libavcodec it checks `avctx->xvmc_acceleration` and/or `avctx->codec->capabilities&CODEC_CAP_HWACCEL_VDPAU` or calls `avctx->get_format(avctx,ff_hwaccel_pixfmt_list_420);` to enable hw decoding in some cases.

In recent version (2017) it and several nearby function do the selection of hw coder https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/aff8cf18cb0b1fa4f2e3d163c3da2f25aa6d1906/libavcodec/mpeg12dec.c#L1189.

Basically: hardware decoder and its api (obsolete [XVMC](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XvMC), [VDPAU](http://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/vdpau/doxygen/html/index.html), [VA API](https://01.org/linuxmedia/vaapi), MS [DXVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX_Video_Acceleration) or MS [Direct3D11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or videotoolbox) should be enabled in your build of ffmpeg and [supported by your hardware](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration) and its driver/libraries (many are proprietary and should be downloaded separately). Sometimes `-hwaccel` option should be given to ffmpeg, or plugin loaded. In linux you may use `vainfo` and `vdpauinfo` commands to test availability and supported profiles with most popular standard video hw decoding APIs.

Input file (for mpeg1/2) should be not Grayscale, it should have `s->chroma_format` less of 2 (4:2:0 [Chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling), which is usual for ISO/IEC MPEG and ITU-T VCEG H.26x; but not for some MPEG-4 Part 2 and not for high 4:4:4 variants of H.264/MPEG-4 AVC).

```
static const enum AVPixelFormat mpeg2_hwaccel_pixfmt_list_420[] = {
#if CONFIG_MPEG2_XVMC_HWACCEL
    AV_PIX_FMT_XVMC,
#endif
#if CONFIG_MPEG_VDPAU_DECODER && FF_API_VDPAU
    AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_MPEG2,
#endif
#if CONFIG_MPEG2_VDPAU_HWACCEL
    AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU,
#endif
#if CONFIG_MPEG2_DXVA2_HWACCEL
    AV_PIX_FMT_DXVA2_VLD,
#endif
#if CONFIG_MPEG2_D3D11VA_HWACCEL
    AV_PIX_FMT_D3D11VA_VLD,
#endif
#if CONFIG_MPEG2_VAAPI_HWACCEL
    AV_PIX_FMT_VAAPI,
#endif
#if CONFIG_MPEG2_VIDEOTOOLBOX_HWACCEL
    AV_PIX_FMT_VIDEOTOOLBOX,
#endif
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
    AV_PIX_FMT_NONE
};

static const enum AVPixelFormat mpeg12_pixfmt_list_422[] = {
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P,
    AV_PIX_FMT_NONE
};

static const enum AVPixelFormat mpeg12_pixfmt_list_444[] = {
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV444P,
    AV_PIX_FMT_NONE
};

#if FF_API_VDPAU
static inline int uses_vdpau(AVCodecContext *avctx) {
    return avctx->pix_fmt == AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_MPEG1 || avctx->pix_fmt == AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_MPEG2;
}
#endif

static enum AVPixelFormat mpeg_get_pixelformat(AVCodecContext *avctx)
{
    Mpeg1Context *s1  = avctx->priv_data;
    MpegEncContext *s = &s1->mpeg_enc_ctx;
    const enum AVPixelFormat *pix_fmts;

    if (CONFIG_GRAY && (avctx->flags & AV_CODEC_FLAG_GRAY))
        return AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8;

    if (s->chroma_format < 2)
        pix_fmts = avctx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO ?
                                mpeg1_hwaccel_pixfmt_list_420 :
                                mpeg2_hwaccel_pixfmt_list_420;
    else if (s->chroma_format == 2)
        pix_fmts = mpeg12_pixfmt_list_422;
    else
        pix_fmts = mpeg12_pixfmt_list_444;

    return ff_thread_get_format(avctx, pix_fmts);
}

static void setup_hwaccel_for_pixfmt(AVCodecContext *avctx)
{
    // until then pix_fmt may be changed right after codec init
    if (avctx->hwaccel
#if FF_API_VDPAU
        || uses_vdpau(avctx)
#endif
        )
        if (avctx->idct_algo == FF_IDCT_AUTO)
            avctx->idct_algo = FF_IDCT_SIMPLE;

    if (avctx->hwaccel && avctx->pix_fmt == AV_PIX_FMT_XVMC) {
        Mpeg1Context *s1 = avctx->priv_data;
        MpegEncContext *s = &s1->mpeg_enc_ctx;

        s->pack_pblocks = 1;
#if FF_API_XVMC
FF_DISABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
        avctx->xvmc_acceleration = 2;
FF_ENABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#endif /* FF_API_XVMC */
    }
}
```

Comment: So do I need to override the pix_fmt of the avctx manually to PIX_FMT_DXVA2_VLD? When I look through the ffmpeg code I only see this value read, never set.

Comment: No file will be PIX_FMT_DXVA2_VLD format. It seems that no documentation exists on FFmpeg hwaccel...

Comment: @Maypeur, Documentation is official now: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro, also check https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration. Your question have no needed details (version of ffmpeg, OS Linux/Windows/Other; what is your hw decoder and is it installed, what is its API, what is your file, how did you start ffmpeg, does hw decode works when starting `ffmpeg` from command line) and can't be answered. But my original answer was not very correct (["doesn't solve anything"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289157/#comment35652265_23289157)), so I updated a bit.

Comment: His questions is about how to integrate hwaccel in a program, the Official documentation only concerns hwo to use it through ffmpeg.exe. It was missing the avctx->pix_fmt = mpeg_get_pixelformat(avctx); before calling avctx->hwaccel = ff_find_hwaccel(avctx->codec->id, avctx->pix_fmt); which seems to change anything ! Thanks for the complete response i will try it today.

Comment: @Maypeur, also useful is the code of ffmpeg.exe to parse hwaccel command line options: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/6294247730549064b1c948c423cf12aa6ff8cf03/ffmpeg_opt.c#L754 `MATCH_PER_STREAM_OPT(hwaccels, str, hwaccel, ic, st);
            if (hwaccel)` & `int show_hwaccels()` & https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/6294247730549064b1c948c423cf12aa6ff8cf03/ffmpeg_opt.c#L3585

Comment: I think there maybe some better example from recent ffmpeg's [source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/4.0/doc/examples/hw_decode.c)

Comment: I found the av_hwaccel_next always return NULL.https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/4.2/libavcodec/utils.c#L1796. And How can I use avctx->hwaccel = ff_find_hwaccel(avctx->codec->id, avctx->pix_fmt); to manual set hwaccel.

Comment: @tbago, Thanks for the update, at 2017-11-26 the `av_hwaccel_next` was deprecated: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/5c0d1f78968ce088b6750a0bfdc2a9c1ddc3692d/doc/APIchanges#L238 "*2017-11-26 - 3536a3efb9 - lavc 58.5.100 - avcodec.h   Deprecate user visibility of the AVHWAccel structure and the functions   av_register_hwaccel() and av_hwaccel_next().*". https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/patch/20171124005134.5683-4-sw@jkqxz.net/ We need to recheck how the ffmpeg works now; if you have detailed question, ask it as new question. Somebody may will help you.