# Initializing hwaccel_context in libavcodec

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration, libavcodec

I am trying to get hardware accelerated video working using libavcodec. I am using the [hw_decode.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/hw__decode_8c_source.html) example as a starting point and am unable to get it to work. both `AVCodecContext->hwaccel` and `AVCodecContext->hwaccel_context` are `NULL`

I belive some part of the hwaccel is working as I see the output

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
```

Which is the same as when I run

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i input.mpg -f null -
```

but immediately after that I get the following error message

```
[h264 @ 0x1df2cc0] Hardware acceleration context (hwaccel_context) does not exist.
Failed to get HW surface format.
[h264 @ 0x1df2cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1df2cc0] no frame!
```

I looked at the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985273/using-ffmpeg-hwaccel-from-c) and the answer to this shows how to get a `AVCodecContext->hwaccel`. But even with the `AVCodecContext->hwaccel` being a valid VAApih264 decoder I still get the same error message.

How do I initialize a `AVCodecContext->hwaccel_context` and after that what else do I need to do to get hardware accelerated video working in ffmpeg?