# FFmpeg -- Using hardware acceleration for video decoding

Tags: c++, c, video, ffmpeg

I have a project that uses FFmpeg to decode video streams and I want to make use of hardware decoding where available. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985273/using-ffmpeg-hwaccel-from-c), the use of `ff_find_hwaccel` and friends is deprecated in newer FFmpeg builds.

The answer states that `ff_find_hwaccel` is deprecated. I want to know how the new method for allocating a hardware accelerated decoder works.  Is it done automatically? Can I just pass `hwaccel` in an AvDictionary as the third option to `avcodec_open2`, or do I have to do something more involved?

Currently the code for allocating an `AVCodecContext` looks like this:

```
auto video_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codec_id);
auto context = avcodec_alloc_context3(video_codec);
auto retcode = avcodec_open2(context, video_codec, nullptr);
```

with error checking, of course.

I then push AVPackets into the decoder using `avcodec_decode_video2`.

Comment: Which platform and OS?  Hardware acceleration is platform dependent.

Comment: The project will mainly be run on Windows x64.

Comment: Would'nt you just allocate the codec context and if it fails you fallback to CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In current versions of FFMPEG hardware acceleration is supported automatically if available. That is also why `ff_find_hwaccel` is deprecated.

Depending on platform and video codec used you might or might not have hardware acceleration support for video decoding. For example hardware accelerated decoding of H264 video has been supported on Nvidia graphics cards for quite a while now using the H264_NVDEC decoder, but HEVC decoding requires a graphics card that is [a fair bit newer](https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-decode-gpu-support-matrix). For AMD graphics cards it's the same story, except that you would normally use the DXVA2 decoder as mentioned [here](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#AMDUVDVCE).

I short: if your platform supports hardware acceleration it should be used automatically by FFMPEG. You could also do additional tests by [forcing a decoder](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#CUDACUVIDNVDEC).